# Transform an array of count data into a matrix of ones and zeroes

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `n` of count data, and I want to transform it into a matrix `x` in which each row contains a number of ones equal to the corresponding count number, padded by zeroes, e.g:

```
n = [0 1 3 0 1]

x = [[ 0.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  1.  1.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  0.  0.]]
```

My solution is the following, and is very slow. Is it possible to do better?

```
n = np.random.poisson(2,5)
max_n = max(n)

def f(y):
    return np.concatenate((np.ones(y), np.zeros(max_n-y)))

x = np.vstack(map(f,n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([0, 1, 3, 0, 1])
max_n = max(n)
np.vstack(n > i for i in range(max_n)).T.astype(int) # xrange(max_n) for python 2.x
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Some crude timing experiments suggest that this answer is about 1.6x faster than @DSM's answer, and almost 400x faster than OP's own attempt. (On `n = np.random.poisson(2,5000)`.)

Comment: That is interesting...I expected @DSM's answer to be faster as it seems to vectorize better.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to vectorize it:

```
>>> n = np.array([0,2,1,0,3])
>>> width = 4
>>> (np.arange(width) < n[:,None]).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

where if you liked, `width` could be `max(n)` or anything else you chose.